# Incomplete Maven artifact transferred

Tags: maven

I'm having problems retrieving certain artifacts when running Maven 3.0.5 from the command-line, for example (after ~20 seconds):

```
...
Could not transfer artifact org.scala-lang:scala-library:jar:2.10.1 from/to central
(http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): GET request of: 
org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.10.1/scala-library-2.10.1.jar from central failed: 
Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 7137903; received: 
6613782 -> [Help 1]
```

I can, however, run a build using m2eclipse, and the artifact is fetched correctly (and once it's in my ~/.m2/repository, I can carry on using the command line).

I'm going through a company proxy. I've sniffed the traffic, and the 6613782 bytes received are correct, it seems the transfer is just terminated early by something.

Any ideas on what could be causing this?

Comment: Can you ask your network/infrastructure guys whether they are seeing anything suspicious on the proxy?